# loading data in postgres using python - reads on the 3rd line and not on the 2nd line

Tags: python, postgresql

i am trying to load some PSV files to Postgres using python, my code has a problem though, it skips 3 lines and starts on the 4th line. I found a code before and I just want it to skip reading the header but it skips 3 lines (including the header) with the code below:

```
import psycopg2
import csv

# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=postgres password=xxxx")

# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()
file = open("/Users/jubertroldan/GNAF/AUG17_GNAF_PipeSeparatedValue_20170821153434/G-NAF/G-NAF AUGUST 2017/Standard/ACT_ADDRESS_DETAIL_psv.psv","r")

with file as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        print(f.readline().count('|'))
        print(f.readline())
        cur.copy_from(f, 'ADDRESS_DETAIL', sep="|",null = '')
        conn.commit()
file.close()
```

here is the readline print below: as you can see it is counting 34 and reading the 3rd line.

```
Juberts-MacBook:GNAF jubertroldan$ python test.py
34
GAACT714878933|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||66|||||ACT571||ACT110|P|2612||CANB/CAMP/36/21/|2|710482401|7|||
```

looking at the data below: looking at GAACT714878933 that is the 4th line. meaning my code to ingest data into postgres is losing data.

```
ADDRESS_DETAIL_PID|DATE_CREATED|DATE_LAST_MODIFIED|DATE_RETIRED|BUILDING_NAME|LOT_NUMBER_PREFIX|LOT_NUMBER|LOT_NUMBER_SUFFIX|FLAT_TYPE_CODE|FLAT_NUMBER_PREFIX|FLAT_NUMBER|FLAT_NUMBER_SUFFIX|LEVEL_TYPE_CODE|LEVEL_NUMBER_PREFIX|LEVEL_NUMBER|LEVEL_NUMBER_SUFFIX|NUMBER_FIRST_PREFIX|NUMBER_FIRST|NUMBER_FIRST_SUFFIX|NUMBER_LAST_PREFIX|NUMBER_LAST|NUMBER_LAST_SUFFIX|STREET_LOCALITY_PID|LOCATION_DESCRIPTION|LOCALITY_PID|ALIAS_PRINCIPAL|POSTCODE|PRIVATE_STREET|LEGAL_PARCEL_ID|CONFIDENCE|ADDRESS_SITE_PID|LEVEL_GEOCODED_CODE|PROPERTY_PID|GNAF_PROPERTY_PID|PRIMARY_SECONDARY
GAACT714880538|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||36|||||ACT561||ACT110|P|2612||CANB/CAMP/43/24/|2|710482728|7|||
GAACT714880557|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||52|||||ACT571||ACT110|P|2612||CANB/CAMP/36/14/|2|710482747|7|||
GAACT714878933|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||66|||||ACT571||ACT110|P|2612||CANB/CAMP/36/21/|2|710482401|7|||
GAACT714879968|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||8|||||ACT3696||ACT568|P|2615||BELC/HOLT/20/15/|2|710472786|7|||
GAACT714907744|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||1|||||ACT1175||ACT212|P|2600||CANB/YARR/13/21/|2|710503118|7|||
GAACT714878965|2004-04-29|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||6|||||ACT4177||ACT575|P|2617||BELC/MCKE/36/24/|2|710472422|7|||
GAACT714886162|2004-10-26|2017-05-09|||||||||||||||6|||||ACT1440||ACT218|P|2604||CANB/NARR/51/4/|2|710494529|7|||
```

any ideas? appreciate the help! thanks a lot

kind regards,
Jubert

Comment: `copy_from` reads the whole file. Do not place it in a loop.

Comment: Not sure how to start reading from the second line though